# How to install WinDbg on a PC without internet connection

Tags: windows-7, windbg

I have to install only the WinDbg (not the complete SDK) on a production system. I can only find a web installer, which needs an internet connection to download the SDK/winDbg.

Is it possible that I install the WinDbg on my system (with an internet connection)  and then copy only the ".exe" file to the production system?

**PS:** Both the computers have ***windows-7.***

Answer (score 6):

It is possible.

I just tried download both [Windows 10 v1703 SDK](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/6/3/36301F10-B142-46FA-BE8C-728ECFD62EA5/windowssdk/winsdksetup.exe) and [Windows 8.1 SDK](https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/0/C/B0C80BA3-8AD6-4958-810B-6882485230B5/standalonesdk/sdksetup.exe) and observe that both accept a `/layout` command-line switch. This allows you to download installation files for later installation. That's what you want, right?

Step-by-step instructions:

1. Download `winsdksetup.exe` (or `sdksetup.exe`)
2. Open Command Prompt
3. Navigate to the folder in which `winsdksetup.exe` is downloaded
4. Issue the following command: `winsdksetup /layout`
5. Select an empty folder into which WinDbg will be downloaded and press Next
6. Unselect components that you don't want to download, i.e. everything but Debugging Tools for Windows and click Download

[image]

Comment: you mean to start the web installer's exe through a command prompt and passing `\layout` during that?

Comment: Not `\layout`!!! It is `/layout`! But yes. Through Command Prompt or Run.

Comment: I tried to run `layout winsdksetup.exe` and got an error `'/layout' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I started cmd.exe as admin.

Comment: Because command-line switch goes **after** the command! So, it would be `winsdksetup.exe /layout`!

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft provides [ISOs for Windows 10 SDK (v1703)](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=845299). Download the ISO on a PC with fast internet and transfer the ISO to your target PC.

Use a 3rd party tool to mount the `15063.137.170329-1903.rs2_release_svc_WindowsSDK.iso`, run `WinSDKSetup.exe` and select the `Debugging Tools for Windows` entry.